how to change the data source from excel to sql server
how to change the data source from excel to SQL server without interrupt the current visualization in power bi,
if i use advance query edition i am getting the current visualization interruption.

You will have to replace the  M code in the Advanced Editor :
Example : I have this data in an Excel sheet called Demo Test :

and I have the same data in a table in SQL Server database :

You already have the data coming from the Excel file in Power BI, so you go to Power Query > Advanced Editor:

Your query will be like below :
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("XXX\Data.xlsx"), null, true),
    #"Demo Test_Sheet" = Source{[Item="Demo Test",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Demo Test_Sheet", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", type text}, {"C", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

You simply replace it with :
let
    Source = Sql.Database(ServerName, DatabaseName),
    dbo_XYZ = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="XYZ"]}[Data]
in
    dbo_XYZ


This is proper answer thanks but if we have calculated columns visuals will effect right.
